# WPF application initialization status

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

Is it possible to know what application is currently doing during loading (initialization)? Similar to what we get in the output window.

Comment: Do you mean that the application itself shall display the same information that is shown in the output window of Visual Studio? Or using an external tool?

Comment: Yes, the application itself, if it is possible. Something to notify user what it is doing currently.

Comment: But if you start without debugging there is nothing to the output window (at least on my PC).  And when an app is loading on it own then it is not running in debug.

Comment: That was only an example of what information I need. I do not need to copy information from output, I need to find the way to get information what is application currently doing / loading, so I can display to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your application have a splash screen, or some other UI it can display during startup? If so, you could put a textblock in the splash screen, and periodically update the textblock with status information. I don't know if there is any way to automatically output status information to this splash screen textblock, most likely you will have to implement something yourself.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, which is: how to get information to be displayed on splash screen? When starting the application, application is loading all the necessary resources for application to run. How do I know what it is currently loading? Never mind where and how will I display it, I need to know how to get the information what is going on.

Comment: But a splash screen is just an image format.

Comment: Again, splash screen is not something you show be bothered with. It is you has mentioned it, not me. The only information I need is how to get the information what is currently being loaded on initialization.

Comment: What significance will it have to the end user if you tell them "Loading MyApplication.MyAssembly.dll"? they don't know nor care what that means. I still don't understand what kind of information you want to display.

Comment: Imagine that my application is large and that it initializes between 3-10 seconds, depending on the PC hardware. Now, if a user sees only a splash screen doing nothing for 10 second, it is not very intuitive, is it? Providing any kind of information that is changing during the loading time is better than nothing, in my opinion.